# How to evaluate Excel format string

Tags: c#, excel, format

**How to evaluate an Excel format string programmatically?**

I am programmatically creating Excel cells based on data in a certain format, e.g xml in
some of the the cells; there are format strings that need to be applied to them.

e.g  "[Red] #,##0.00" for 987564.63635

before filling into the cell, I want to check (basically only colors) for the cell or text.
In case it is won't display well to the user, e.g light yellow is very bad, a user can hardly see this color.

So it comes to before creating the cell, I need to know the color from the format string
e.g "[Red] #,##0.00" or "[Color 32] dd/mm/yyyy" or an even more complex Excel format string.

I want to know.  Is there some kind of library that can do this job?
or does .net have this kind of function already?
or i have to do it by myself?

**Sample**

e.g 
if format string is "[Red] #,##0,00", 
i want to know the corresponding Sysmte.draw.Color for the [Red] base on the string.
or the corresponding web color, ff0000, for [Red] base on the string 
or corresponding  RGB values

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "evaluate", perhaps illustrating with an example what the input is and what the corresponding output should be. Is "[Red] #,##0.00" the input? Would "Red" then be the output? Or (255,0,0)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Excel range object to access all the cell's configuration setup.

for example:

```
Worksheet sheet = excelApp.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet;
Range r = sheet.Cells[1, 1];
MessageBox.Show(r.Value2 + "\n" + r.Text + "\n" + r.NumberFormat);
```

r.Value2 holds the underline value of the cell (the formula).

r.Text holds the visible (user) value of the cell (the result).

r.NumberFormat holds the format string - in your example it will hold the "[Red] #,##0.00".

From there you'll need to use any string manipulation techniques on the NumberFormat member (i recommend a regular expression) to find the color you are looking for or any other thing.

**EDIT**, here is some usage of regExp and TypeCovertor to accomplish the string to Color object conversion. (with a continue to the above source)

```
string formatString = r.NumberFormat;
Regex colorRegExp = new Regex(@"^\[(?<color>\S+)\]", RegexOptions.Compiled);

Color resultColor;
System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter converter = System.ComponentModel.TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(new Color());

Match m = colorRegExp .Match(formatString);
if (true == m.Success)
{
   string colorString = m.Groups["color"].Value;
   resultColor = (Color)converter.ConvertFromString(colorString);
}
```

The regular expression object is compiled to the assembly for performance. I assume using the `Color resultColor` object is something you can figure yourself (it has ARGB and other members to examine).

And last comment, you can easily reduce the number of lines in this example, i just wanted to emphasize each step on the way.

Comment: "use any string manipulation techniques on the NumberFormat member" I think that's what the OP is asking how to do...

Comment: @Corbett: thanks for pointing this, somehow i missed the original question ;-), see my update above